# Блокировка редактирования элемента, если его кто-то уже редактирует

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Есть spa-приложение на blazor. Требуется сделать блокировку элемента для остальных пользователей и уведомление для них, если этот элемент кто-то уже редактирует. На текущий момент есть одна идея:

1. Добавить в таблицу сущности столбец LockedUserId(кем заблокирована) и LockedTime(когда). В конфиге проекта хранить время блокировки.
2. При загрузке страницы пользователь подписывается на hub(signalr) и конкретно на методы, уведомляющие о блокировке и ее отмене.
3. Если пользователь открывает элемент для редактирования, то он вызывает помимо post метода еще и signalr метод о блокировке. Signalr отправляет всем уведомление о блокировке.
4. После успешного редактирования/отмены пользователь вызывает или не вызывает нужный api, но в любом случае вызовет signalr метод об отмене блокировки.
5. Если пропадает соединение с пользователем или он перезагрузил страницу, то вызывается OnDisconnected signalr метод и заблокированная сущность разблокируется, а также отправится уведомление всем остальным пользователям о снятии блокировки.

Является ли это решение оптимальным?

Comment: Пессимистичная блокировка - зло! Пользователь начнёт редактировать элемент и уйдёт на обед. Или в отпуск. Или вообще умрёт... Разруливать такие ситуации очень сложно. Поэтому оптимистическая блокировка лучше почти всегда. [Блокировка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Блокировка_(СУБД))

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov инфу по ссылке пока не прочитал, но забыл добавить, что блокировку на n минут хотел делать(~15).

Comment: Почему бы не реализовать совместное редактирование безо всяких блокировок? Стильно, модно, современно.

Comment: @aepot современно спору нет, но в разы сложнее.

Comment: Так этот велосипед уже придуман, надо просто найти матчасть, дело техники. Ну или если по-приколу можно свой изобрести. Блокировка, когда ее возможно избежать - худшее решение из всех.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov прочитал про оптимистичную блокировку. Сразу к примеру. Есть форма редактирования: textbox, combobox и.т.п При пессимистичной я бы смог отправить 1 patch метод и поменял всю сущность целиком. При оптимистичной, если я долго редактировал данные и при сохранении мне приходит исключение о том, что они уже изменены. Что в таком случае делать? Предлагать пользователю перезагрузить форму и/или автоматически загрузить данные в контролы?

Comment: _Что в таком случае делать?_ - то же самое, что вы будете делать в случае пессимистичной блокировки, когда время (n минут) истечёт. Когда блокировка на n минут закончится и снимется, элемент может быть взят другим пользователем. Потом оба его пытаются сохранить. Как вы будете это решать? Ну, вот.

Comment: @Lapish Вам верно подсказывают, что пессимистичных блокировок лучше избегать, всех сложностей, с которыми вы сталкиваетесь в заданном вопросе, можно избежать просто показывая пользователю окошко вроде "элемент был изменён другим пользователем, загрузить снова? да, нет"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь придумать механизм для обработки пессимистичных блокировок, сегодня в отрасли есть консенус о том, что подобного дизайна стоит избегать. Поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос - нет, это не оптимально.
В вашей ситуации обычно действуют следующим образом:

1. Вместо обновления всей сущности через HTTP-метод PUT используют частичное обновление методом PATCH. Таким образом вы сможете значительно уменьшить число ситуаций где блокировка вообще нужна - если у объекта "Адрес" Вася изменил улицу, а Петя номер дома, то они оба правы и мы можем занести это в базу.
2. Если таки и Вася и Петя одновременно захотели поменять именно номер дома, то последнему записывающему данные на клиенте просто выводится сообщение о том, что данные уже были изменены и их нужно перечитать. Тут вы уже можете прикрутить какой-то механизм, который автоматически перечитывает, объединяет с изменением пользователя и делает запрос снова, но это уже зависит от вашей задачи (может быть слишком дорого-богато). Например, компания Atlassian в продукте Jira делает обновления задач в трекере по стратегии "побеждает последний", т.е. даже не показывает пользователю, что его изменение конфликтует с другим, а просто тихо перезаписывает. Если Петя сказал, что правильный номер дома теперь 23, то, скажем, если у нас не финансовые транзакции, нам фактически всё равно перезаписывает он 31-й дом или 25-й.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!